# Dynamic SQL with variables for table and returned values output

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Struggling with query. Made several changes but cannot get it to work.

The procedures work by themselves as a query but do not work when called with in another procedure; since I cannot see the variable values populated when I Debug

any help is appreciated?

```
            Exec dbo.usr_GetLastDate @TableName, @LastTransDate
            EXEC dbo.usr_GetRecCount @TableName, @RecCount

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetLastDate]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTDATE date Output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTDATE=MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTDATE DATE OUTPUT', @OUTDATE=@OUTDATE OUTPUT;

END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetRecCount]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTINT int output

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTINT=COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);


   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTINT INT OUTPUT', @OUTINT=@OUTINT OUTPUT;
END
```

Comment: Why are you tagging mysql and sql-server ?

Comment: You need to visit back to the question you have asked before and accept the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using visual studio
you can see all the variables values in the Variables window. Expressions will only show values when they have scopes, but sometimes they do not behave the way we want to.

So my suggestion is you should use "Variables" window to view all the variables and its value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword OUTPUT when passing OUTPUT variables to the procedures

```
Exec dbo.usr_GetLastDate @TableName, @LastTransDate OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.usr_GetRecCount @TableName, @RecCount OUTPUT
```

Comment: Like I said before you need to visit back to all the questions you have asked before and accept the answers that helped you, so other users who maybe asking the same question can know which answer solved the problem for you. Be a useful member of this community

Answer (score 0):

The final code that worked. Thank you all

```
** Main Procedure **
Exec dbo.usr_GetLastDate @TableName, @LastTransDate OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.usr_GetRecCount @TableName, @RecCount OUTPUT

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetLastDate]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTDATE date Output
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTDATE=MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTDATE DATE OUTPUT', @OUTDATE=@OUTDATE OUTPUT;

END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_GetRecCount]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @OUTINT int output
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @OUTINT=COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);


   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand, N'@OUTINT INT OUTPUT', @OUTINT=@OUTINT OUTPUT;
END
```